# Understanding 策に出る

Tags: phrases

> 〈ジャガーノート〉の主兵装は、敵のそれとは比べるのもおこがましい貧弱な五七ミリ砲、堅牢を極めた重戦車型の装甲など前後左右、どの位置からでもいかな近距離でも撃ちぬけない。有効な攻撃箇所はただ一点、そこを狙える位置まで接近するため、まずはその巨体の死角を外から補う目を潰し、付け入る隙を増やす**策に出た**。

86─エイティシックス─

What does に出る mean here? Does 策に出る mean the same as 策を講じる?

Answer (score 5):

[策を講じる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%AC%9B%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8B/#jn-73624) is not so different from 策に出る. But the former implies careful planning while the latter means simply *to take a strategy*.

As such 講じた sounds more of an earlier phase than 策に出た, which implies the strategy already started to be executed.

In the particular case, 策を講じた wouldn't sound totally off. But my impression is that 講ずる comes naturally for X(のための)策を講じる, where X is the objective of the strategy. So here 接近するための策を講じた would be more natural. In other words, 出る is more appropriate here because it is saying *took the strategy of まずは...隙を増やす*.

---

As another example, 強硬策に出る is possible but 強硬策を講じる sounds odd. This is because 強硬策 means (literally) *strong/brutal measures*, i.e., a kind of last resort that needs little planning.

Comment: Thank you. So what is the definition of this 出る in dictionary? And how should I make sense of this に?

Comment: @chinoalpha I guess practically it is better remembered as a set phrase, but に as [動作・作用の行われ方、その状態のあり方を表す。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166083) and でる as [ある態度をとる。ある態度で相手に対する。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B/#jn-152769) are relevant (considering a strategy as an attitude in a broad sense).